# How to share document in Flutter app using Whatsapp_share_2 dependency?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to share documents using whatsapp_share2 plugin in pub dev but I am getting error I try to do that with file picker but not working please help I'm geeting PlatformExaption.

```
  Future<List<String?>> getPath() async {
    final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true);
    print('object==>${result?.paths}');
    return result == null ? <String>[] : result.paths;
  }

  Future<void> shareFile() async {
    final filePaths = await getPath();
      var list = filePaths;
      var withoutNulls = list.whereType<String>().toList();
    await WhatsappShare.shareFile(
      text: 'Whatsapp share text',
      phone: '918160994731',
      filePath: ["${withoutNulls}"],
    );
  }
```